# Usage of "Vanessa" in Open All Hours

Tags: british-english

In the episode "Duet for solo bicycle" - 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCnc8hUPuPU&t=4m22s

Albert Arkwright says - "No need to get all Vanessa about it."

> 00:04:00 I made progress last night with the aid of some C--Cyprus sherry.
>   00:04:04 She's still sticking to her principles, but only just!
>   00:04:10 G--G--Granville, did you warm that pot?
>   00:04:13 No, I warmed that one over there!
>   00:04:16 You always ask me that every meal time. You say, "G--G--Granville, did you warm that pot?"
>   00:04:22 -- I always warm the pot. -- No need to get all Vanessa about it!
>   00:04:30 -- Have we got to have bacon again? -- You like bacon.

From the context I guessed the meaning as something in the lines of "diva", etc.

What's the story behind the usage?

Comment: For those that can't watch the video, can you please provide some of the conversation around this line for context?

Comment: Is there a Vanessa character on the show? Before that line, the other character seems to be mimicking someone.

Comment: Could be referencing [Vanessa Feltz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanessa_Feltz) or *Vanessa* used as slang for woman.

Comment: @Barman I cannot remember a *Vanessa* in the series. Wiki does not list one in cast either.

Comment: [Full script](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=open-all-hours-1973&episode=s03e03)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Vanessa Sky Ellis is 28 years old. The episode "Duet for Solo Bicycle" 1st aired in April 1982 and was probably written the previous year.

Comment: Vanessa --> fuss? As in: “there's no need to make such a fuss”. Maybe “*get so sensitive/touchy/testy/flustered*”?

Comment: @Christopher: Oh lord! Do we *really* care who was having their five minutes of fame over thirty years ago?

Comment: @FumbleFingers listening to the clip, it sounds like Arkwright is eating his words, maybe the actor, Ronnie Barker, fluffed his line but carried on relentlessly. rightly so the OP is confused, especially seeing it garnered a few titterings from the live studio audience. A famous Vanessa in the late 70s? [Vanessa Redgrave](https://www.google.it/search?q=vanessa+redgrave&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=kFonVeuHG5HmaMC2gtgE&ved=0CJYBEIke&biw=1366&bih=653) comes to mind, but I can't imagine her warming a pot of tea though... :)

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I didn't actually listen to the clip (or even register the *age*) until just now. Having thought about it *in context*, I'd say the reference is indeed to Vanessa Redgrave - she had a reputation as an activist, and was also probably the *only* "Vanessa" famous enough to be referenced like that in a popular tv show. So in context it's *"No need to get all [theatrically] **worked up**"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, of course! David Jason/ Arkwright is **imitating** Barker/Granville's voice, as an actor or actress would. He's mimicking his uncle's mannerisms. Spot on!